# Maze dead end filter check

Tags: c, filter, solver, maze

I created a program that runs through a ASCII maze but I wan't to create a filter for the following situation:

```
    ####
    ..X#
    ####
```

'#' means a wall.
'X' means the location.
'.' is the 'breadcrum' left behind.

I could also resemble this, because it is located in a matrix, as follow:

```
    ####     [(x-1, y-1)][(x-1, y)][(x-1, y+1)]
    ..X# --> [(x, y - 1)][( x, y )][(x, y + 1)]
    ####     [(x-1, y-1)][(x+1, y)][(x+1, y+1)]
```

There are 4 situtions possible, so I made an else if statement in C,

```
else if(mazePointer->matrix[curX-1][curY] == '#' &&
        mazePointer->matrix[curX][curY+1] == '#' &&
        mazePointer->matrix[curX+1][curY] == '#'){
        walkPointer->newX = curX;
        walkPointer->newY = curY-1;

        mazePointer->matrix[curX][curY] = '+';

        return 1;   
}
```

var curX & curY being the matrix coordinations at that moment.

this example suits the matrix coordinates of the uppermost given example. What I want to do in the situation is go 1 space back and put a '+' on my location before I went a space back. This will garantee that I will not end up in the same situation, because it is not possible to end up at a place that is 'marked' with a '+'. I can only land on places either empty or filled with a '.'.

But know comes the strange thing, in my opinion strange, because this 'filter' will just skip over the current situation. The statements won't be true. Can anyone explain me what I am messing up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the '&' which is a bit-wise operator. You want to use the '&&' boolean "AND" operator instead.

Comment: Tried it but I won't fix my issue.

Comment: it looks like your new walkPointer is moving in the Y direction while your mase shows a horizontal (X) case. Setting walkPointer->newX = curX - 1 instead.

Comment: No that's not the case cause I only want the Y to be -1, I want it to move left. Otherwise I will locate itself at another 1 to the top. Besides that the statement still seems to be 'false' all the time. When I print printf("(%c(%i,%i)),",mazePointer->matrix[curX-1][curY], curX-1, curY); for all the statements I get 3 x '#' which is good cause thats what i wanted. But still skips it :(

Comment: Try embedding the if statements. If it skips it, then one of the conditions should be failing

i.e.

        if (...) { if (...) { if (...) {} } }

or step through the if statements with a debugger.

Comment: You are right! Changing the 'else if' statements into 'if' statements did the trick